# Enterprise Service Bus architecture

Tags: architecture

Quick architecture question.

I am needing to set up a portal/website with a database This is easy but now I want to add on functionality for apps, and other clients to interact through an API.

My first thought was put an ESB in the architecture. The Website , apps and clients connect to the ESB and the ESB connects to the database.

I am looking at doing load balancing on the portal and load balancing on the ESB if possible.

Would this be advisable? If so I am now implementing the ESB, would it go being something like IIS or would I connect directly to the ESB?

Concerns include - losing messages, and the performance of the ESB that it will not slow down the queries to the DB for the portal ect.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ESB works well for complex integration projects. If you are looking for something simple I would suggest to start from exposing your API via some sort of RPC mechanism (JSON-RPC/XML-RPC/REST/SOAP/etc.). If your requirements ever grow to the point when you actually need an ESB it will be easy to integrate your API into ESB endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the advantages of using RPC in my scenario .